# Is there any difference in writing a inline xslt in a xml file(like build.xml) and writing it in different xslt file

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have written one xsl that is working fine when called from XSLT ant task. But when same script is embedded in build.xml it is giving error on execution.

Here is my xsl :

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="XMLFilePath"/> 
<xsl:param name="updates" select="document($XMLFilePath)" />
<xsl:variable name="updateItemsServlet" select="$updates/ee:web-app/ee:servlet" />
<xsl:variable name="updateItemsServlet-mapping" select="$updates/ee:web-app/ee:servlet-mapping" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ee:web-app">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::ee:servlet)] | ee:servlet[not(ee:servlet-name = $updateItemsServlet/ee:servlet-name)]" /> 
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateItemsServlet" />
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First input file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="ProcessExecutor" version="2.4">
        <display-name>ProcessExecutor</display-name>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/config/beans-stgsuite-enterprise.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>  
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>download</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>download</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/download/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/send/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Second input file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    id="ProcessExecutor" version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <description>Omi GetDocument</description>
        <display-name>omiGetDocument</display-name>
        <servlet-name>omiGetDocument</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.majescomastek.stgicd.policy.commons.utility.GetOMIDocumentChain</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>omiGetDocument</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/omiGetDocService/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description>PDF Downloader</description>
        <display-name>pdfDownloader</display-name>
        <servlet-name>pdfDownloader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.majescomastek.ho.comparativerater.pdf.downloader.QuoteProposalPdfDownloader</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pdfDownloader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdfService/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Embedded in xml means ..inline xslt. Added the same xsl in build file as below.

```
<target name="MyXSLT">
   <xslt in="web.xml" out="output.xml">
      <param name="XMLFilePath" expression="icd-service-web"/>
        <style>
                <string>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="XMLFilePath"/> 
<xsl:param name="updates" select="document($XMLFilePath)" />
<xsl:variable name="updateItemsServlet" select="$updates/ee:web-app/ee:servlet" />
<xsl:variable name="updateItemsServlet-mapping" select="$updates/ee:web-app/ee:servlet-mapping" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ee:web-app">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::ee:servlet)] | ee:servlet[not(ee:servlet-name = $updateItemsServlet/ee:servlet-name)]" /> 
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateItemsServlet" />
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
                    ]]>
                </string>
        </style>
    </xslt>
</target>
```

Comment: here is the error log :

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: _isNotSecureProcessing
     [xslt] : Error! javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apach
e.xml.internal.utils.URI$MalformedURIException: The scheme is not conformant.
     [xslt] Failed to process D:\Automation_Ant\xsltExample\MergeWebXML\web.xml

BUILD FAILED
D:\Automation_Ant\xsltExample\MergeWebXML\build.xml:4: javax.xml.transform.Trans
formerException: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.TransletException: java
x.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.URI$
MalformedURIException:

Comment: Can you provide us with the input XML a well? Thanks.

Comment: It also would be better to edit your post to add the error stacktrace.

Comment: What exactly does "*embedded in build.xml*" mean? Please post enough code for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: using ant target xslt to execute the xsl